# How can I parse an XML with multiple root elements using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, root

I am trying to read this XML file using PHP and I have two root elements. The code that I wrote in PHP reads only one root element and when I add the other one (`<action>`) it gives me an error.
I want to do something like this : `if($xml->action=="register")` then print all parameters.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<action>register</action>
<paramters>
    <name>Johnny B</name>
    <username>John</username>    
</paramters>
```

And this is my PHP script:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
}
?>
```

I really don't know how to do all this...

Comment: Your XML is invalid. XML files can only have 1 root node

Comment: Agreed, this is not well-formed and hence not XML. Fix whatever produced it. Also, you are echoing to HTML without calling `htmlspecialchars()` on the output string, which will fail (potentially with security implications) if the values contain HTML-special characters like `<`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your XML, it's invalid. XML files can only have 1 root element.

Example valid XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<action>
    <type>register</type>
    <name>Johnny B</name>
    <username>John</username>
</actions>
```

Or if you want only parameters to have own elements:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<action type="register">
    <name>Johnny B</name>
    <username>John</username>
</actions>
```

or if you want multiple actions:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<actions>
    <action type="register">
        <name>Johnny B</name>
        <username>John</username>
    </action>
</actions>
```

**EDIT**:

As I've said in my comment, your teacher should fix his XML. It is [invalid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element). Also he should put his XML through [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

If you're really desperate you can introduce an articificial root element, but this is really bad practice and should be avoided at all costs:

```
$xmlstring = str_replace(
    array('<action>','</paramters>'),
    array('<root><action>', '</paramters></root>'),
    $xmlstring
);
```

Comment: Then point your teacher to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element . Also tell him to put his XML through a validator: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now. Thank you very much!

Comment: lol i have the same problem and actually the gov is using that kind of mess.... so they wont fix it.... I actually need a way to read millions of xmls with multiple root elements

Answer (score 3):

None of the previous answers is quite accurate. The XML specification defines several kinds of entity: document entities, external parsed entities, document type definitions for example. Your example is not a well-formed document entity, which is what XML parsers are normally asked to parse. However, it is a well-formed external parsed entity. The way to process a well-formed external parsed entity is to reference it from a skeletal document entity, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE wrapper [
<!ENTITY e SYSTEM "my.xml">
]>
<wrapper>&e;</wrapper>
```

and then pass the document entity to the XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

As it is an `invalid` xml file, you can do the following trick.

- Insert a dummy start tag at the second line as `<dummy>`
- In the end finish it with `</dummy>`

Happy parsing ;)

Comment: Bad advice, he should just fix his XML shema, not do a trick like this

Comment: "I am trying to read this xml file using PHP and i have two root elements." He should have been aware of this. I am so angry why this is downvoted? @dtech

Comment: As I said, I consider it very bad advice to give this kind of solution without any type of context. This should be your last resort and not your first quick fix.